# r.js optimizer not appending baseURL to module name

Tags: javascript, optimization, requirejs, r.js

I'm trying to optimize a module in my project but I'm getting an error that the module does not exist because r.js does not seem to be adding the baseURL to the file path.

Here is my build profile (app.build.js):

> {
>       appDir: "app",
>       baseUrl: "web/static/durandal_app",
>       dir: 'app_build',
>       optimizeCss: 'none',
>       modules: [
>          {
>             name: 'dashboard/dashboard.js'
>          }
>        ],
>        mainConfigFile: 'app/web/static/durandal_app/dashboard/main.js',
>   }

Here is my directory structure:

/User/sahil/Documents/ 
| 
|--app.build.js 
| 
|--app/ 
|    |--web/ 
|    |     |--static/ 
|    |     |    |--durandal_app/ 
|    |     |    |       |--dashboard/ 
|    |     |    |       |      |-- main.js 
|    |     |    |       |      |-- dashboard.js

This is the error message I get back:

> Error: Error: ERROR: module path does not exist: dashboard/dashboard.js for module named: dashboard/dashboard.js. Path is relative to: /Users/sahil/Documents
>       at /Users/sahil/Documents/node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js:24307:35

Looking at the error message it seems like it's not appending the appDir or baseUrl to the module path, but I can't figure out why. I know I'm passing the appDir correctly because it creates a copy of it at app_build. I've spent 2 days banging my head against this problem, please help!!

Comment: I figured out the problem...the module name shouldn't have the .js extension. Can't believe I wasted so much time because of that...

Comment: thank you, solves the problem